# Rails user has many users through users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I'm fairly new to rails, and working on an app which essentially allows users to report grievances about other users (just a fun app i want to use with friends). Basically there are just two models, users and reports. A user has many reports and reports belong to a user (ie. a user is associated to reports submitted about them)

Basic model structure:

```
class User<ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reports  
end

class Report<ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Right now, users can submit new reports and select from a dropdown which user to associate it with, but I would also like to add an association between the report and the user who submitted the report so that I can go through the reports that a user has made and find the user they reported about most. (ie. I want users to have many reports which were written about them and have many reports which they wrote about others)

I don't know how to accomplish this because i need to distinguish this has_many/belongs to relationship from the one I have above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want something like a `reporter association`, this can be accomplished with an optional reference from the `report` table to the `user` table:

So on your `report model` add the line below:

```rb
belongs_to :reporter, class_name: :User, foreign_key: 'reported_by_id', optional: true
```

Then generate a `migration` and add the code below:

```rb
add_reference :reports, :reported_by, index: true
```

Then you can do something like:

```rb
report.reporter = user1
report.save
or
user2 = report.reporter
```

Then to get the `reports` that a particular `user` made:

```rb
Report.where(reported_by_id: user.id)
```

[This may help with the migration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), you can simply run `rails g migration <name_of_your_migration>`, this will generate a file with that name and add the code above inside the `change function`.

The above example is on `rails 5.2`, what you are saying with the fix above is exactly: besides the relation, I as `report` has with the table `users`, I also have an especial relation with a particular user (you can make that relation optional or not if you have data already in your database I think you should do it `optional`). I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks. I think this looks like exactly what I want. Could you clarify what I should do when you say ‘generate a migration’? I get kinda confused with the syntax for using the generators

Comment: Happy to help!, please if the answer looks correct for you mark it as accepted  @Will Worrell